# Battery Performance

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I have reset my Laptop(DELL INSPIRON 15 (3542)) and I am using Windows 10. Before reset, when the charging level down to 50% the screen brightness decreases by 25%. But after reset, I am unable to do this. Kindly tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the **Start Menu**
- Go to **Settings**
- Go to **System**
- On the left side click on **Battery**
- Find the checkbox that says "**Turn battery saver on automatically if my battery falls below:**" and select it.
- You'll see a sliding scale right underneath the checkbox you just selected. Slide that over to your desired 50% level.
- Underneath the sliding scale you just adjusted you'll see a checkbox that says "**Lower screen brightness while in battery saver.**" Select that and you're done.

[image]